# Aggregate rows on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to figure out a way to aggregate (make a flat list of) several rows, with a PeriodIndex, as a forward rolling window. I would like the window to be 2 quarters (or 6 months). When using rolling('2Q') I get a non-monotonic index error, and if I try to .resample() before the rolling function, I get a non-uniquely valued index error. I don't want to remove duplicate indexes as I am trying to get a rolling window of 2 indexes (all such rows) at a time.

Sample data (date is the index):

```
date    html_text                                                    
2011Q1  [a, b, c]   
2011Q1  [d, e, f]  
2011Q2  [j, k, l]   
2011Q2  [m, n, o]
2011Q3  [u, v, w]
2011Q3  [x, y, z]
...
```

I'll also add that the rolling window is being computed within a for loop that is going through my date index as:

```
for period in sorted(set(df.index))[:-2]:
```

And preference for a solution would be one that looks at the periodIndex equivalent of [period:period+2] This of course doesn't work because period is not an integer.

EDIT: Here is the result I am looking for:

```
date    html_text
2011Q1  [j, k, l, m, n, o, u, v, w, x, y, z]
2011Q2  ...
```

.groupby() seems promising but I've had a hard time with it as well (similar error messages)

Comment: What result are you trying to get? if your dataframe is
    date    data
    2011Q1 [a, b, c]
    2011Q1 [d, e, f]
    2011Q2 [x, y, z]
    2011Q2 [t, u, v}

Are you trying to get your window of two quartes get a value of `[a, b, c, d, e, f, x, y, z, t, u, v]`, or something else?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added desired results now, hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first grouping on `date` (you can 1df.reset_index()1 to create a `date` column), thus:

```
df = df.reset_index()
foo= df.groupby('date').agg(lambda x: [i for j in x for i in j])
foo.set_index('date')
boo = foo.rolling('2Q').gg(lambda x: [i for j in x for i in j])
```